# Mix C and Objective-C Memory Management

Tags: objective-c

1.
Considering the following code:

```
void make_objc_array()
{
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @2, nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", array.lastObject);
}

void make_objc_dictionary()
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@1, @"1", @2, @"2", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", dictionary[@"2"]);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        make_objc_array();
    }
    make_objc_dictionary();
    return 0;
}
```

Does `make_objc_dictionary();` function call leaks `NSDictionary` object since it is outside `@autorelease` block?

2.
Consider this code snippet:

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    NSNumber *num[2] = {@1, @2};
    ...
}
```

For memory management, is there anything I need to do for an `NSObject` C array, or ARC will do the correct thing? Or is there any case ARC would not work when mixing C and Objective-C?

Comment: ARC will handle `make_objc_dictionary`. I'm not 100% sure on ARC semantics of C style arrays since there is little reason to use them over an `NSArray`. It should be noted you cannot mix `C` and `Objective-C` since the latter is a strict superset of `C`; therefore `C` code is part of `Objective-C`.

Comment: Some clarification: ARC will not handle anything you `malloc` (or similar). You must obey all standard `C` memory management rules. ARC only manages `retain` and `release` (and similar) messages to Objective-C objects. I _believe_ it would handle your example just fine due to the fact that there is no allowed use of manual `release` under ARC. I _think_ the objects in the C array will be released when the array goes out of scope and the array itself is on the stack and needs no memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[M]ixing C and Objective-C" is no different that programming in Objective-C. Objective-C **includes** C. There's nothing in any of your code snippets which is not Objective-C.

ARC will do the right thing in your examples. ARC doesn't manage most non-object memory allocation. It doesn't manage CoreFoundation. It doesn't manager `malloc()` and similar functions.

Another case where ARC can't help is if you create strong reference cycles.

Finally, programs don't leak memory "permanently" — that is, after they've exited. If your program is about to exit, such as the `return` from `main()`, you don't need to worry about the memory you allocated because it will all be reclaimed by the operating system when your program terminates.